# odbc query returns the first row twice then returns the rest normally

Tags: php, sql, database, odbc

I am querying a database with an odbc connection through php. When I query the db it returns the first row twice and then the rest of the rows the correct amount of times.

Example query:

```
$stm = SELECT[sUsername] FROM [dbo].[Abilis].[Users] WHERE sUsername = ?;
$pstm = odbc_prepare($conn, $stm);
$exc = odbc_execute($query, array($Username));
```

I have also tried using DISTINCT but that has not worked either.

EDIT:

```
for($i=0; $i<odbc_num_rows($pstm);$i++){

            $row = odbc_fetch_array($pstm, $i);
            if($row['OnCreditHold'] == '1'){
              $out = '<button style="color:red;margin:0 auto;" class="btn" onclick="'.'window.location.href='."'information.php?info=".$row['Account_no'];
              $out .= "'".'">'.$row['Name'].'</br>';
              $out .= $row['Del_ad1'].'</button>';
            }
            else{
              $out = '<button class="btn" style="margin: 0 auto;" onclick="'.'window.location.href='."'information.php?info=".$row['Account_no'];
              $out .= "'".'">'.$row['Name'].'</br>';
              $out .= $row['Del_ad1'].'</button>';

            }
            echo $out;
          }
```

Comment: Make sure that you don't have that username inserted twice

Comment: What happens if you run the query outside of your php application?

Comment: Could you add some code to show how you're iterating through the resultset?

Comment: If I run it outside the application there is no duplicates.

Comment: @WhiteSnow - I have a vague memory that the odbc_ functions return result sets that are 1-indexed, rather than 0-indexed as you'd expect (I can't find anything on the man pages to back this up, aside from a note on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-result.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have checked the query result is good outside of this app -- good for you.  That means the problem is your loop structure, or maybe your method of getting the data such as `odbc_fetch_array()`.

I ran into this problem once, and I can't recall the solution.  I had to try alternative methods to isolate the cause.

For example, instead of `for ()`, try `foreach ($elems as $elem) { ... }`.

Of course, simplify all the other aspects while you are trouble-shooting.  For example, remove the `if()` structure.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the function odbc_fetch_array ($pstm, $i) with the second parameter starting with zero causes the problem. When you use 0, and the second time 1, it will give you the same result. You could use a while-loop instead of a for-loop and don't use the second parameter.

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result))
{
   // do something
}
```